# error while running `detox build -c android.emu.debug` Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED in react native

Tags: android, react-native, detox

While following the Detox [installation tutorial for android][1], I had the following error running the `detox build -c android.emu.debug`

---

> **❯ detox build -c android.emu.debug** detox[23052] INFO:  [build.js] cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest
>   -DtestBuildType=debug && cd ..
>
> > Task :app:generatePackageList
> >     Task :app:preBuild
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-reanimated:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-reanimated:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-reanimated:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-reanimated:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-screens:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-screens:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-screens:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-screens:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-vector-icons:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-vector-icons:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-vector-icons:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-vector-icons:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-webview:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-webview:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-webview:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-webview:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-vector-icons:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-webview:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-reanimated:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-screens:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-vector-icons:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-webview:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:bundleDebugJsAndAssets SKIPPED
> >     Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> >     Task :react-native-gesture-handler:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
>
> **> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager.java:4:
>   error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist**
>   import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
>                                               ^ /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager.java:17:
>   error: cannot find symbol @ReactModule(name =
>   RNGestureHandlerRootViewManager.REACT_CLASS)  ^   symbol: class
>   ReactModule
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:16:
>   error: package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist
>   import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
>                                               ^ /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:19:
>   error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIBlock;
>                                      ^   symbol:   class UIBlock   location: package com.facebook.react.uimanager
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:40:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>   @ReactModule(name=RNGestureHandlerModule.MODULE_NAME)  ^   symbol:
>   class ReactModule
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java:218:
>   error: cannot find symbol   @ReactProp(name = ViewProps.BORDER_RADIUS)
>                                ^   symbol:   variable BORDER_RADIUS   location: class ViewProps
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerEvent.java:41:
>   error: method init in class Event cannot be applied to given types;
>       super.init(handler.getView().getId());
>            ^   required: int,long   found: int   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length   where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Event declared in class Event /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNViewConfigurationHelper.java:45:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>         return parent.getChildAt(((ReactViewGroup) parent).getZIndexMappedChildIndex(index));
>                                                           ^   symbol:   method getZIndexMappedChildIndex(int)   location: class ReactViewGroup
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNViewConfigurationHelper.java:54:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               String overflow = ((ReactViewGroup) view).getOverflow();
>                                                        ^   symbol:   method getOverflow()   location: class ReactViewGroup
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:574:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       final int rootViewTag = uiManager.resolveRootTagFromReactTag(ancestorViewTag);
>                                        ^   symbol:   method resolveRootTagFromReactTag(int)   location: variable uiManager of type
>   UIManagerModule
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:582:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           if (root.getRootView().getRootViewTag() == rootViewTag) {
>                                 ^   symbol:   method getRootViewTag()   location: class ReactRootView
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:598:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock() {
>                                ^   symbol:   class UIBlock   location: class RNGestureHandlerModule
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:634:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       int rootViewTag = uiManager.resolveRootTagFromReactTag(viewTag);
>                                  ^   symbol:   method resolveRootTagFromReactTag(int)   location: variable uiManager of type
>   UIManagerModule
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerModule.java:641:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>           if (root.getRootView().getRootViewTag() == rootViewTag) {
>                                 ^   symbol:   method getRootViewTag()   location: class ReactRootView
>   /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerPackage.java:18:
>   error: RNGestureHandlerPackage is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method createJSModules() in ReactPackage public class
>   RNGestureHandlerPackage implements ReactPackage {
>          ^ /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent.java:45:
>   error: method init in class Event cannot be applied to given types;
>       super.init(handler.getView().getId());
>            ^   required: int,long   found: int   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length   where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Event declared in class Event Note: /home/rogerd/dev/app_cachacagestor/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/gesturehandler/react/RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for
>   details. 16 errors
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it
>   incompatible with Gradle 6.0. Use '--warning-mode all' to show the
>   individual deprecation warnings. See
>   https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 5s 22 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 20 up-to-date
>   detox[23052] ERROR: [cli.js] Error: Command failed: cd android &&
>   ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug &&
>   cd ..

---

"react": "16.8.6",

"react-native": "0.60.5",

"detox": "^14.3.2",

"mocha": "^6.2.0",

---

Does anyone know how to solve ?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. 1- Deprecated code should generally be avoided. 2- It says "package com.facebook.react.module.annotations does not exist" so you may be missing adding something into your project.

Comment: hey did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the order of the maven repositories in android/build.gradle. My allprojects looks like this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    }
    maven {
        // Android JSC is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
    }
    maven {
        // All of Detox' artifacts are provided via the npm module
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android"
    }
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
}
```

}

Thanks to [gypsicoder](https://github.com/gypsicoder)

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/1002